# Writing a unit test for a method with two HTTP calls with Mockito and jUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have three methods,

- void save(String a, String b)
- String getId(String a, Pojo p)
- void update(String a, String b, StringEntity c)

Here are the implementations(not the full implementation),

```
String getId(String accessToken, Pojo p) {

    //Note that the pojo is for formatting the payload for the request, nothing more

    HttpResponse response = httpRequestService.makeGetRequest(url, TOKEN_PREFIX, accessToken,
            CONTENT_TYPE);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        log.debug("Success");
    }

    //Code for getting the id from the response

    return id;
}

void update(String accassToken, String id, StringEntity payload) {

    HttpResponse response = httpRequestService.makePutRequest(url + id,
            TOKEN_PREFIX, accessToken, CONTENT_TYPE, payload);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        log.debug("Success");
    }
}

void save(String accessToken, String payload) {

    //The getId() is called here
    String id = getId(/*arguments*/);

    if(id == null) {
        log.error("Error");
    } else {
        //The update() is called here
        update(/*arguments*/);
    }
}
```

As mentioned, the getId and update methods are called inside save method and both getId and update methods have HTTP calls.

I have to write a unit test for the save() method. This is what I tried.

```
    //This is an interface with methods to call HTTP requests.
    HttpRequestService httpRequestService = Mockito.mock(HttpRequestService.class);

    //Constructor injection
    ClassWithMethods a = new ClasswithMethods(httpRequestService);

    HttpResponse responseGet = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);
    StatusLine statusLineGet = Mockito.mock(StatusLine.class);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = Mockito.mock(HttpEntity.class);
    Mockito.when(responseGet.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(statusLineGet);
    Mockito.when(statusLineGet.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(200);
    Mockito.when(responseGet.getEntity()).thenReturn(httpEntity);
    Mockito.when(httpEntity.getContent()).thenReturn(IOUtils.toInputStream(stream));
    Mockito.when(httpRequestService.makeGetRequest(url, TOKEN_PREFIX, accessToken,
            CONTENT_TYPE).thenReturn(responseGet);

    HttpResponse responsePut = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);
    StatusLine statusLinePut = Mockito.mock(StatusLine.class);
    Mockito.when(responsePut.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(statusLinePut);
    Mockito.when(statusLinePut.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(200);
    Mockito.when(httpRequestService.makePutRequest(url + id, TOKEN_PREFIX,
            accessToken, CONTENT_TYPE, payloadEntity).thenReturn(responsePut);

    a.save(accessToken, payload);
```

But when testing, the responsePut returns a null. The arguments are also matching.

**Problem** : How to test this save method which calls two HTTP methods?

This may not be the best way to do this. If there better ways to test a method like this, please suggest.

Thank you

Note that, httpRequestService is an interface with methods for HTTP calls and the constructor injection is used too.

Comment: "But when testing, the responsePut returns a null. " A variable doesn't return anything. Please more explicit in the actual behavior and also show the failure test message.

Comment: @davidxxx, It just throws a NullPointerException at the line,
 
`if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)`

in the update() method. When I debugged it, it shows the responsePut is null.

Comment: Identifying the error line matters to understand or guess the cause. I did an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should extract the following into a separate method (same goes for PUT):

```
HttpResponse response = httpRequestService.makeGetRequest(url, TOKEN_PREFIX, accessToken,
            CONTENT_TYPE);
```

Then you can stub that method using mockito's:

```
when(obj.methodGET(...)).thenReturns(...)
```

**Remember**: your unit-tests should *not* make calls over-the-wire!

**EDIT**

```
private HttpResponse get(String url, ...) {
    return httpRequestService.makeGetRequest(url, TOKEN_PREFIX, accessToken,
            CONTENT_TYPE);
}


private HttpResponse put(String url, ...) {
    return httpRequestService.makePutRequest(url + id,
        TOKEN_PREFIX, accessToken, CONTENT_TYPE, payload);
}
```

And then:

```
...
when(mockedStatusLineObj.getStatusCode()).thenReturns(200);
HttpResponse mockedGet = mock(HttpResponse.class);
when(mockedGet.getStatusLine()).thenReturns(mockedStatusLineObj);
when(object.get(...)).thenReturns(mockedGet);
when(object.put(...)).thenReturns(...);
```

Comment: Those are already in separate methods, PUT is in 'update()' method and GET is in 'getId()' method. Do you mean those methods should be called separately instead of calling them in the same 'save()' method?

Comment: @Agent47 no it's not: see the edit to understand better what I'm talking about

Comment: @alfasin Extracting the methods in the same class as private methods implies that you have to mock methods of the object under test by using spy() or any "trick". I think that the actual OP design is good.

Comment: @davidxxx sure, if you can mock objects that you have no access to, using spies - that's great. I don't know how to do it, but I'd love to learn!

Comment: @alfasin, But with how I did this, after adding `Mockito.anyString()` and `Mockito.any(StringEntity.class)` as the arguments appropriately to the following, I could get the test passed.

`Mockito.when(httpRequestService.makePutRequest(url + id, TOKEN_PREFIX,
            accessToken, CONTENT_TYPE, payloadEntity).thenReturn(responsePut);`

I know the arguments must be matched to return the mock response properly. But I checked if there is anything to do with the arguments, I couldn't see any difference. Adding the real arguments instead of `Mockito.any()` doesn't pass the test. Why?

Comment: Now it looks like a totally different question. In case it is - please post it as a new question with all the relevant information. As you can see - it's not easy to read code that is embedded in comments...

Comment: Hope you understood the main idea though: 1. unit-tests should not make calls over the wire. 2. when you refactor your code you can eliminate such calls by mocking the responses.

Comment: @alfasin The problem is that spy() is not necessary the correct way. It is the no choice way. "Spies should be used carefully and occasionally, for example when dealing with legacy code."

Comment: @alfasin, No, it is not a different one. It is completely relevant to this question. What I mentioned in the comment is, when mocking, I could get the test passed after using `Mockito.any()` as arguments. But using real arguments, the test fails.

Comment: @Agent47 it's relevant to you *case* but it's a totally different question than the one you posted above, that's why it should be treated separately.

Answer (score 1):

**About your way of testing**

Actually, your test setup is fine but complicated to read.
A test has to keep readable and simple.
Otherwise understanding and maintaining it becomes hard.
You want to mock `HttpRequestService`.
It is a good way if you want to `unit-test` your class and don't want consider integration concerns.
But the way you mock dependencies of the mocked `HttpRequestService` makes the code not readable :

```
HttpResponse responsePut = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);
StatusLine statusLinePut = Mockito.mock(StatusLine.class);
Mockito.when(responsePut.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(statusLinePut);
Mockito.when(statusLinePut.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(200);
```

And you repeat this at each invocation.
Extract them in a method :

```
public HttpResponse createMockedHttpResponse(String url){
    HttpResponse responsePut = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);
    StatusLine statusLinePut = Mockito.mock(StatusLine.class);
    Mockito.when(responsePut.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(statusLinePut);
    Mockito.when(statusLinePut.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(200);
    return responsePut;
}
```

**About the test failure**

> It just throws a `NullPointerException` at the line,
>
> `if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)` in the `update()`
> method.
>
> When I debugged it, it shows the responsePut is null.

If I look your actual code, these invocations in the class under test :

```
getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

are correctly mocked here :

```
HttpResponse responsePut = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);
StatusLine statusLinePut = Mockito.mock(StatusLine.class);
Mockito.when(responsePut.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(statusLinePut);
Mockito.when(statusLinePut.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(200);
```

By elimination, it means that the recorded behavior at the next statement was not encountered:

```
Mockito.when(httpRequestService.makePutRequest(url + id, TOKEN_PREFIX,
        accessToken, CONTENT_TYPE, payloadEntity).thenReturn(responsePut);
```

So ensure you that the record behavior for  `makePutRequest()` and the actual invocation of `makePutRequest()` have exactly same / `equals()` passed parameters.
If some parameters are not really required for the test logic, don't hesitate to pass `Mockito.any()`

Comment: Yeah, after adding Mockito.any() I could get the test passed. But with the real arguments, it fails. But I cannot find a difference in the arguments either. :-(

Comment: You can find the unmatched parameter(s) by testing `any()` for a single parameter and do the same thing for the next one until you find all unmatched .

Comment: @alfasin  Never. My refactoring proposal is extracting method of the unit test class, not of the class under test. Besides, it would make no sense to  propose it as I explained as comment in your answer that this practice should be avoided.